# Azure DevOps - Test Plans - State - Active/Inactive meaning

Tags: azure, devops

I have a basic question regarding the state transitions for test plans. Currently I only have the options of active/inactive and I couldn't really find any information on what they mean. If I create a test plan for a particular sprint, then when the sprint is over should the state automatically be inactive?
Sorry if it's a silly question, I tried google but maybe I'm using the wrong keywords and can't find the answer.

Thanks in advance!